Running a hidden API in R - increase speed
I am a beginner in R, and I am trying to go through a list of refCodes for articles on the EC website to scrape the titles, text, etc. The code for doing this takes super long though, 4+ hours, as it goes through 50,000+ refcodes:
for (refcode in combined_dataframe$refCode) {
  tryCatch({
  url_2 <- paste0("https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/api/documents?reference=", refcode, "&language=en&ts=1715285692126")
    res_2 <- getURL(url_2, .opts=list(httpheader = headers_2, followlocation = TRUE))
  second_api_responses[refcode] <- res_2
}, error = function(e) {
  cat("Error fetching data for refcode:", refcode, "\n")
})
}

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to improve this?
I tried to work around with the code using parallel processing for the loop, but since each request is smaller in size the parallel processing does not change that much I feel.
